# C# MVC .net asp net framework protected constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, class

Hola Buenas noches camaradas, tengo una gran duda con una propiedad protected dentro de una clase padre, quiero desde mi vista insertarle datos a través de un input pero me dice que no se puede instanciar el objeto ayuda. La idea es crear un Domicilio pero para eso tengo que instanciar la clase protegida pero no me permite.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Es mejor compartir parte del código así es mas fácil que la comunidad puede ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un constructor protegido significa que solo los miembros derivados pueden construir instancias de la clase (e instancias derivadas) usando ese constructor.

Como sabemos, se puede declarar un constructor como privado para evitar que el código del cliente cree una instancia directa de un objeto. Pero entonces ya no se puede "subclasificar" la clase, porque la clase derivada no tendrá acceso al constructor.

Si lo que se desea es una semántica de constructor privada, pero que aún pueda crear una subclase, lo que se puede hacer es que un constructor esté protegido (protected). Otro código no podrá construir instancias de la clase base, pero su subclase podrá llamar al constructor.

Comment: Buenos días Iván , antes que nada muchas gracias por tu tiempo en ayudarme. Entonces tendría que instanciar el contructor en una clase derivada. Cómo podría hacerlo, puedes enviarme un ejemplo como para probar . Desde ya te agradezco